# Listbox horizontal scroll doesn't wrap the whole textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox with a textblock (as an ItemTemplate), which can contain a long text, so I set the horizontal scrolling, but even doing this, inside the textblock I didn't have the whole text, only if I set also the wrapping of the text:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfText, Mode=OneWay}"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So setting the wrapping for the TextBlock

```
TextWrapping="Wrap"
```

Fixes this issue, but I don't want the TextBlock to wrap on multiple lines, I want a single line and if I want to see the end of the text to only scroll to the end (horizontally). It behaves like the horintal scrolling would have a maximum number of pixels to show, which I don't think it's the case.

Comment: Should work just fine provided that you put the `ListBox` in a panel with an constrained width. Please post your complete XAML markup.

Comment: I really think that it could be a bug.. I mean the Horizontal scrollbar appears, it scrolls, but only the 1/3 of the text block's content appears, and I am sure that the full content is bound to it.

Comment: Also the List box is hosted as one of a Grid's row (width set to *).

Comment: You still haven't posted your actual markup and provided a reproducible example so it's highly unlikely a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a TextBlock add a Grid with 2 columns.  Assign the 2nd column's width a value of 1.  Place your TextBlock inside the Grid on column 0.  Now it will wrap.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />    </Grid>
```

Comment: The full solution has a Grid with 3 columns, where the Text Block is the third column with Width set to "*". I just didn't post the full solution so it's easier to read.

Comment: Also 2 things to mention, the second column does nothing probably, the second is that I don't want it to wrap, I want to fully scroll, right now if I have a text with 50k chars, it only scrolls like 15k chars.

Comment: Evidently I completely misunderstood your question because my solution will absolutely cause the text to wrap and fit.